# How to create relationships between custom entities

Tags: office365, dynamics-crm-2011

I am new to CRM dynamics 365. I have a task to create something for a retail store client. Now retail stores can be multiple and so can customers be multiple. For customers shall I use out of box entity 'Account'?

Since the store is a custom entity, how am I going to map customers to it? Customers can be mapped to different stores. Later, when a case is created for service, I need to enter the mobile number of the customer and then the details of the store from where the purchase was made should appear. What approach should I follow? How can achieve this?

Comment: How do customers related to a store? Are you tracking invoices through CRM?

Comment: Thanks for replying kye. This will be for demonstration purpose. No invoices are going to be data source as such as of now. We just want them to have a taste about our Dynamics CRM.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define ***why*** an account relates to a store and choose to use either:

1. An OOB entity type, such as Incident (for servicing requests), Invoice (for purchase) or Activity (capturing communication)
2. A custom entity type you create.
3. CRM Connection entity with a custom role.

You'll get the most online support for options #1 or #3.

Comment: Currently on opening any case I get this error : "Query builder error , the specified field does not exist in microsoft dynamics 365 "

Comment: @mohdtahir you have logic referring a field which no longer appears. Maybe you deleting a field or added a business rule to prevent it from appearing. We were able to resolve this issue.  Open your IE --> Tool --> Advanced  Uncheck --> "Show friendly HTTP error messages" and hope the error message makes more sense.

Comment: I tried doing this but It doesn't shows anything still.

Comment: I get this log error message , 'Incident' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'IncidentResolution_LinkControl'.

Comment: This error came out since I tried editing a  business process flow "Phone to Case". How can I resolve this ? Any suggestions?

Comment: If your still developing - can you create a new organisation?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by organisation. But I am able to create a new account as well as new contacts.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Kye, But I want know why organisation is relevant to this error?

Comment: If possible can you please share the screenshot of a default Phone to Case business Process flow. So that I can revert the changes.

Comment: If you create a new organisation, you will be able to see one.

Comment: But what I see is that creating a new organisation is not applicable for Dynamics 365 online version? It's for on-premise I guess.

Comment: please can't you share such a snapshot if possible?

Comment: I'm not in front of a computer.